how do I turn an animation into a pre-loader
basically I saw a lot of youtube videos on how to make pre-loaders, however, all of them instead of teaching how to actually make a pre loader, just show a cool animation. I have already made an animation that works I just can't figure out how to make the actual pre-loader of the website. By pre-loader I mean, I want the animation to show while the website is loading in the background and after 4 seconds of the animation showing I want the website to appear.


.kosa {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.kul {
  position: relative;
  /* display: none; */
}

.svg1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -140;
}

.kul svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.kosa::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<%3Fxml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"%3F><svg viewBox="0 0 1795 236" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:v="https://svgstorm.com"><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".02" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m0 236h209c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39c0.06 12.63 0.06 26.57 0 39s0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.78 11.8-5.37 17.62s-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45c-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.93 4.06-17.75 5.81h316c-19.13-5.24-37.25-12.86-45.39-33.75-8.15-20.9-9.08-62.22-7.61-91.25s-1.8-59.99 9.13-77.92 27.97-29.15 49.87-29.08c-0.42-3.28-5.45-0.46-5-4h-558v236m119-120c15.64 8.05 22.82 15.33 22.78 37.22s2.13 56.75-1.78 78.78c-17.7-0.02-38.32-0.02-56 0-2.3-14.21-0.48-33.97-1-50s1.51-34.11-3-47c-2.61 0.55-5.35-1.27-9-2 0.02 32.53-0.03 66.19 0 98-19.63 1.67-43.47 1.64-63 0v-222c20.39-5.47 56.89-0.34 77.22-0.22 20.34 0.12 35.02 3.46 45.86 17.14 10.85 13.67 9.95 29.34 10.92 50.08s-5.71 33.73-23 40m267-109c4.92 12.85 5.33 26.69 7.66 40.68s3.39 25.96 5.34 40.32c5.7-27.99 5.78-54.54 12-81 25.07 1.33 55.51-2.64 79 2-0.67 73.41 1.34 149.34-1 223-17.05-0.06-36.97 0.01-54 0-3-32.67 1-67.74-2-100-4.49 34.03-7.52 68.31-14 100-12.05-0.04-26.96-0.04-39 0-7.05-35.2-8.76-65.57-16-101-0.66 33.58 1.33 67.87-1 101-17.33-0.67-38.06 1.29-55-1v-222c10.81-2.5 25.19-0.26 38-1s27.52 1.38 40-1z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m557 236h31c19.26-4.31 38.94-11.66 47.8-33.25s7.48-58.31 7.2-88.75 1.76-62.52-9.13-80.92c-10.89-18.39-29.19-29.08-51.87-30.08 0.3-1.25 1.83-1.71 2-3h-26c-0.45 3.54 4.58 0.72 5 4-21.9-0.07-38.94 11.15-49.87 29.08s-7.66 48.89-9.13 77.92-0.54 70.35 7.61 91.25c8.14 20.89 26.26 28.51 45.39 33.75m11-45c-0.15-22.21-0.58-49.94 0-74s-2.58-51.15 2-71c13.26 0.18 9 14.97 10 28s-0.36 33.3 0 47 0.05 33.93 0 47 1.01 30.08-12 23z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".02" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m588 236h524c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39 0.06 26.57 0 39 0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.78 11.8-5.37 17.62s-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45c-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.92 4.06-17.75 5.81h247c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39c0.06 12.63 0.06 26.57 0 39s0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.79 11.8-5.37 17.62-2.59 5.82-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.92 4.06-17.75 5.81h267c-19.61-6.41-38.84-12.46-46.19-35.25s-8.67-68.84-6.81-98.75-2.12-57.24 12.3-74.7c14.41-17.47 33.06-25.48 58.7-25.3s44.21 9.96 57.13 27.92 10.17 48.33 10.87 79.08 1.36 69.42-6.58 91.77c-7.93 22.35-28.07 30.54-47.42 35.23h73v-236h-1211c-0.17 1.29-1.7 1.75-2 3 22.68 1 40.98 11.69 51.87 30.08 10.89 18.4 8.85 50.48 9.13 80.92s1.66 67.16-7.2 88.75-28.54 28.94-47.8 33.25m319-231c2.19 16.35 0.63 35.55 1 54s-0.27 38.27 0 57-0.35 38.16 0 57-1.09 38.59 1 57c-13.03 3.16-31.53-1.1-46 2-2.18-13.41-0.67-29.47-1-45s0.17-32.13 0-48 0.13-33.02 0-49c-41.48 47.69-83.78 94.09-125 142-16.76-1.62-35.27-1.69-52 0-1.88-1.73-1.1-3.04-2-5 51.5-57.3 103.25-115.92 155-175-51.24 0.67-103.2-1.33-154 1-3.16-13.02 1.1-31.53-2-46 16.35-2.19 35.54-0.63 54-1s38.27 0.27 57 0 38.16 0.34 57 0 38.59 1.09 57-1m146 50c-10.49 4.76-26.95 0.62-40 2v36h35c1.63 15.14 1.63 31.85 0 47h-35c0.02 30.19-0.03 61.53 0 91-19.36 2.34-42.33 0.28-62 1-2.34-72.99-0.32-149.73-1-223 9.97-1.85 24.1-1.16 36-1s27.36-0.78 39 0 28.1-5.48 27 8 0 26.1 1 39m279-46c-0.03 14.71-0.03 32.31 0 47-10.83 2.3-22.75 0.36-34 1-0.66 58.13 1.32 117.89-1 175-19.38 0-41.61-0.05-61 0-0.01-57.5 0.01-116.81 0-175-10.59 0.64-21.86-1.29-32 1-3.01-6.01-3-18.79-2-27s-4.92-23.4 5.03-23.02c9.94 0.38 21.71-0.19 31.97 0.02 10.27 0.21 21.68-0.22 32 0s21.86-0.37 32 0 20.91-1.28 29 1m269 107c15.64 8.05 22.82 15.33 22.78 37.22s2.14 56.75-1.78 78.78c-17.7-0.02-38.32-0.02-56 0-2.3-14.21-0.48-33.97-1-50s1.51-34.11-3-47c-2.61 0.55-5.35-1.27-9-2 0.02 32.53-0.03 66.19 0 98-19.36 2.34-42.33 0.28-62 1-1.8-23.76-1.02-49.14-1-74s-0.41-52.19 0-77-1.95-51.61 2-74c18.44 0.36 45.35-0.53 63.25 0.2 17.89 0.72 31.87 2.05 43.05 7.51 11.19 5.47 19.52 15.4 22.41 26.59 2.89 11.18 3.91 33.64 2.08 46.93-1.84 13.29-7.41 24.54-21.79 27.77z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1690 236h32c19.35-4.69 39.49-12.88 47.42-35.23 7.94-22.35 7.28-61.02 6.58-91.77s2.05-61.12-10.87-79.08-31.49-27.74-57.13-27.92-44.29 7.83-58.7 25.3c-14.42 17.46-10.44 44.79-12.3 74.7s-0.54 75.96 6.81 98.75 26.58 28.84 46.19 35.25m11-45c-0.15-22.21-0.58-49.94 0-74s-2.58-51.14 2-71c13.26 0.18 9 14.97 10 28s-0.36 33.3 0 47 0.05 33.93 0 47 1.01 30.08-12 23z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m907 5c-18.41 2.09-38.16 0.66-57 1s-38.27-0.27-57 0-38.54-0.37-57 0-37.65-1.19-54 1c3.1 14.47-1.16 32.98 2 46 50.8-2.33 102.76-0.33 154-1-51.75 59.08-103.5 117.7-155 175 0.9 1.96 0.12 3.27 2 5 16.73-1.69 35.24-1.62 52 0 41.22-47.91 83.52-94.31 125-142 0.13 15.98-0.17 33.13 0 49s-0.33 32.47 0 48-1.18 31.59 1 45c14.47-3.1 32.97 1.16 46-2-2.09-18.41-0.65-38.16-1-57s0.27-38.27 0-57 0.37-38.55 0-57 1.19-37.65-1-54z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m119 116c17.29-6.27 23.97-19.26 23-40s-0.07-36.41-10.92-50.08c-10.84-13.68-25.52-17.02-45.86-17.14-20.33-0.12-56.83-5.25-77.22 0.22v222c19.53 1.64 43.37 1.67 63 0-0.03-31.81 0.02-65.47 0-98 3.65 0.73 6.39 2.55 9 2 4.51 12.89 2.48 30.97 3 47s-1.3 35.79 1 50c17.68-0.02 38.3-0.02 56 0 3.91-22.03 1.74-56.89 1.78-78.78s-7.14-29.17-22.78-37.22m-48-22v-43c12.75-0.75 11.12 10.22 11 21s2.56 21.91-11 22z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m209 236h32c7.82-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45s5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62c0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.06-26.37 0-39c-0.05-12.63 0.2-26.42 0-39s0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m386 7c-12.48 2.38-27.19 0.26-40 1s-27.19-1.5-38 1v222c16.94 2.29 37.67 0.33 55 1 2.33-33.13 0.34-67.42 1-101 7.24 35.43 8.95 65.8 16 101 12.04-0.04 26.95-0.04 39 0 6.48-31.69 9.51-65.97 14-100 3 32.26-1 67.33 2 100 17.03 0.01 36.95-0.06 54 0 2.34-73.66 0.33-149.59 1-223-23.49-4.64-53.93-0.67-79-2-6.22 26.46-6.3 53.01-12 81-1.95-14.36-3.01-26.33-5.34-40.32s-2.74-27.83-7.66-40.68z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1053 55c-1-12.9-2.1-25.52-1-39s-15.36-7.22-27-8-27.1 0.16-39 0-26.03-0.85-36 1c0.68 73.27-1.34 150.01 1 223 19.67-0.72 42.64 1.34 62-1-0.03-29.47 0.02-60.81 0-91h35c1.63-15.15 1.63-31.86 0-47h-35v-36c13.05-1.38 29.51 2.76 40-2z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1112 236h32c7.83-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45s5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62c0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.05-26.37 0-39 0.2-26.42 0-39 0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1332 9c-8.09-2.28-18.86-0.63-29-1s-21.68 0.22-32 0-21.73 0.21-32 0c-10.26-0.21-22.03 0.36-31.97-0.02-9.95-0.38-4.03 14.81-5.03 23.02s-1.01 20.99 2 27c10.14-2.29 21.41-0.36 32-1 0.01 58.19-0.01 117.5 0 175 19.39-0.05 41.62 0 61 0 2.32-57.11 0.34-116.87 1-175 11.25-0.64 23.17 1.3 34-1-0.03-14.69-0.03-32.29 0-47z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1391 236h32c7.83-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45 2.58-5.82 5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62 0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.06-26.37 0-39c-0.05-12.63 0.2-26.42 0-39s0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1601 116c14.38-3.23 19.95-14.48 21.79-27.77 1.83-13.29 0.81-35.75-2.08-46.93-2.89-11.19-11.22-21.12-22.41-26.59-11.18-5.46-25.16-6.79-43.05-7.51-17.9-0.73-44.81 0.16-63.25-0.2-3.95 22.39-1.59 49.19-2 74s0.02 52.14 0 77-0.8 50.24 1 74c19.67-0.72 42.64 1.34 62-1-0.03-31.81 0.02-65.47 0-98 3.65 0.73 6.39 2.55 9 2 4.51 12.89 2.48 30.97 3 47s-1.3 35.79 1 50c17.68-0.02 38.3-0.02 56 0 3.92-22.03 1.74-56.89 1.78-78.78s-7.14-29.17-22.78-37.22m-48-22v-43c12.75-0.75 11.12 10.22 11 21s2.56 21.91-11 22z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".05" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m568 191c13.01 7.08 11.95-9.93 12-23s0.36-33.3 0-47 1-33.97 0-47 3.26-27.82-10-28c-4.58 19.85-1.42 46.94-2 71s-0.15 51.79 0 74z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".05" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1701 191c13.01 7.08 11.95-9.93 12-23s0.36-33.3 0-47 1-33.97 0-47 3.26-27.82-10-28c-4.58 19.86-1.42 46.94-2 71s-0.15 51.79 0 74z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".04" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m71 94c13.56-0.09 10.88-11.22 11-22s1.75-21.75-11-21v43z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".04" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1553 94c13.56-0.09 10.88-11.22 11-22s1.75-21.75-11-21v43z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".02" stroke="None"><path d="m0 236h209c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39c0.06 12.63 0.06 26.57 0 39s0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.78 11.8-5.37 17.62s-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45c-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.93 4.06-17.75 5.81h316c-19.13-5.24-37.25-12.86-45.39-33.75-8.15-20.9-9.08-62.22-7.61-91.25s-1.8-59.99 9.13-77.92 27.97-29.15 49.87-29.08c-0.42-3.28-5.45-0.46-5-4h-558v236m119-120c15.64 8.05 22.82 15.33 22.78 37.22s2.13 56.75-1.78 78.78c-17.7-0.02-38.32-0.02-56 0-2.3-14.21-0.48-33.97-1-50s1.51-34.11-3-47c-2.61 0.55-5.35-1.27-9-2 0.02 32.53-0.03 66.19 0 98-19.63 1.67-43.47 1.64-63 0v-222c20.39-5.47 56.89-0.34 77.22-0.22 20.34 0.12 35.02 3.46 45.86 17.14 10.85 13.67 9.95 29.34 10.92 50.08s-5.71 33.73-23 40m267-109c4.92 12.85 5.33 26.69 7.66 40.68s3.39 25.96 5.34 40.32c5.7-27.99 5.78-54.54 12-81 25.07 1.33 55.51-2.64 79 2-0.67 73.41 1.34 149.34-1 223-17.05-0.06-36.97 0.01-54 0-3-32.67 1-67.74-2-100-4.49 34.03-7.52 68.31-14 100-12.05-0.04-26.96-0.04-39 0-7.05-35.2-8.76-65.57-16-101-0.66 33.58 1.33 67.87-1 101-17.33-0.67-38.06 1.29-55-1v-222c10.81-2.5 25.19-0.26 38-1s27.52 1.38 40-1z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m557 236h31c19.26-4.31 38.94-11.66 47.8-33.25s7.48-58.31 7.2-88.75 1.76-62.52-9.13-80.92c-10.89-18.39-29.19-29.08-51.87-30.08 0.3-1.25 1.83-1.71 2-3h-26c-0.45 3.54 4.58 0.72 5 4-21.9-0.07-38.94 11.15-49.87 29.08s-7.66 48.89-9.13 77.92-0.54 70.35 7.61 91.25c8.14 20.89 26.26 28.51 45.39 33.75m11-45c-0.15-22.21-0.58-49.94 0-74s-2.58-51.15 2-71c13.26 0.18 9 14.97 10 28s-0.36 33.3 0 47 0.05 33.93 0 47 1.01 30.08-12 23z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".02" stroke="None"><path d="m588 236h524c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39 0.06 26.57 0 39 0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.78 11.8-5.37 17.62s-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45c-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.92 4.06-17.75 5.81h247c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39c0.06 12.63 0.06 26.57 0 39s0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.79 11.8-5.37 17.62-2.59 5.82-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.92 4.06-17.75 5.81h267c-19.61-6.41-38.84-12.46-46.19-35.25s-8.67-68.84-6.81-98.75-2.12-57.24 12.3-74.7c14.41-17.47 33.06-25.48 58.7-25.3s44.21 9.96 57.13 27.92 10.17 48.33 10.87 79.08 1.36 69.42-6.58 91.77c-7.93 22.35-28.07 30.54-47.42 35.23h73v-236h-1211c-0.17 1.29-1.7 1.75-2 3 22.68 1 40.98 11.69 51.87 30.08 10.89 18.4 8.85 50.48 9.13 80.92s1.66 67.16-7.2 88.75-28.54 28.94-47.8 33.25m319-231c2.19 16.35 0.63 35.55 1 54s-0.27 38.27 0 57-0.35 38.16 0 57-1.09 38.59 1 57c-13.03 3.16-31.53-1.1-46 2-2.18-13.41-0.67-29.47-1-45s0.17-32.13 0-48 0.13-33.02 0-49c-41.48 47.69-83.78 94.09-125 142-16.76-1.62-35.27-1.69-52 0-1.88-1.73-1.1-3.04-2-5 51.5-57.3 103.25-115.92 155-175-51.24 0.67-103.2-1.33-154 1-3.16-13.02 1.1-31.53-2-46 16.35-2.19 35.54-0.63 54-1s38.27 0.27 57 0 38.16 0.34 57 0 38.59 1.09 57-1m146 50c-10.49 4.76-26.95 0.62-40 2v36h35c1.63 15.14 1.63 31.85 0 47h-35c0.02 30.19-0.03 61.53 0 91-19.36 2.34-42.33 0.28-62 1-2.34-72.99-0.32-149.73-1-223 9.97-1.85 24.1-1.16 36-1s27.36-0.78 39 0 28.1-5.48 27 8 0 26.1 1 39m279-46c-0.03 14.71-0.03 32.31 0 47-10.83 2.3-22.75 0.36-34 1-0.66 58.13 1.32 117.89-1 175-19.38 0-41.61-0.05-61 0-0.01-57.5 0.01-116.81 0-175-10.59 0.64-21.86-1.29-32 1-3.01-6.01-3-18.79-2-27s-4.92-23.4 5.03-23.02c9.94 0.38 21.71-0.19 31.97 0.02 10.27 0.21 21.68-0.22 32 0s21.86-0.37 32 0 20.91-1.28 29 1m269 107c15.64 8.05 22.82 15.33 22.78 37.22s2.14 56.75-1.78 78.78c-17.7-0.02-38.32-0.02-56 0-2.3-14.21-0.48-33.97-1-50s1.51-34.11-3-47c-2.61 0.55-5.35-1.27-9-2 0.02 32.53-0.03 66.19 0 98-19.36 2.34-42.33 0.28-62 1-1.8-23.76-1.02-49.14-1-74s-0.41-52.19 0-77-1.95-51.61 2-74c18.44 0.36 45.35-0.53 63.25 0.2 17.89 0.72 31.87 2.05 43.05 7.51 11.19 5.47 19.52 15.4 22.41 26.59 2.89 11.18 3.91 33.64 2.08 46.93-1.84 13.29-7.41 24.54-21.79 27.77z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m1690 236h32c19.35-4.69 39.49-12.88 47.42-35.23 7.94-22.35 7.28-61.02 6.58-91.77s2.05-61.12-10.87-79.08-31.49-27.74-57.13-27.92-44.29 7.83-58.7 25.3c-14.42 17.46-10.44 44.79-12.3 74.7s-0.54 75.96 6.81 98.75 26.58 28.84 46.19 35.25m11-45c-0.15-22.21-0.58-49.94 0-74s-2.58-51.14 2-71c13.26 0.18 9 14.97 10 28s-0.36 33.3 0 47 0.05 33.93 0 47 1.01 30.08-12 23z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m907 5c-18.41 2.09-38.16 0.66-57 1s-38.27-0.27-57 0-38.54-0.37-57 0-37.65-1.19-54 1c3.1 14.47-1.16 32.98 2 46 50.8-2.33 102.76-0.33 154-1-51.75 59.08-103.5 117.7-155 175 0.9 1.96 0.12 3.27 2 5 16.73-1.69 35.24-1.62 52 0 41.22-47.91 83.52-94.31 125-142 0.13 15.98-0.17 33.13 0 49s-0.33 32.47 0 48-1.18 31.59 1 45c14.47-3.1 32.97 1.16 46-2-2.09-18.41-0.65-38.16-1-57s0.27-38.27 0-57 0.37-38.55 0-57 1.19-37.65-1-54z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m119 116c17.29-6.27 23.97-19.26 23-40s-0.07-36.41-10.92-50.08c-10.84-13.68-25.52-17.02-45.86-17.14-20.33-0.12-56.83-5.25-77.22 0.22v222c19.53 1.64 43.37 1.67 63 0-0.03-31.81 0.02-65.47 0-98 3.65 0.73 6.39 2.55 9 2 4.51 12.89 2.48 30.97 3 47s-1.3 35.79 1 50c17.68-0.02 38.3-0.02 56 0 3.91-22.03 1.74-56.89 1.78-78.78s-7.14-29.17-22.78-37.22m-48-22v-43c12.75-0.75 11.12 10.22 11 21s2.56 21.91-11 22z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m209 236h32c7.82-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45s5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62c0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.06-26.37 0-39c-0.05-12.63 0.2-26.42 0-39s0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m386 7c-12.48 2.38-27.19 0.26-40 1s-27.19-1.5-38 1v222c16.94 2.29 37.67 0.33 55 1 2.33-33.13 0.34-67.42 1-101 7.24 35.43 8.95 65.8 16 101 12.04-0.04 26.95-0.04 39 0 6.48-31.69 9.51-65.97 14-100 3 32.26-1 67.33 2 100 17.03 0.01 36.95-0.06 54 0 2.34-73.66 0.33-149.59 1-223-23.49-4.64-53.93-0.67-79-2-6.22 26.46-6.3 53.01-12 81-1.95-14.36-3.01-26.33-5.34-40.32s-2.74-27.83-7.66-40.68z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m1053 55c-1-12.9-2.1-25.52-1-39s-15.36-7.22-27-8-27.1 0.16-39 0-26.03-0.85-36 1c0.68 73.27-1.34 150.01 1 223 19.67-0.72 42.64 1.34 62-1-0.03-29.47 0.02-60.81 0-91h35c1.63-15.15 1.63-31.86 0-47h-35v-36c13.05-1.38 29.51 2.76 40-2z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m1112 236h32c7.83-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45s5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62c0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.05-26.37 0-39 0.2-26.42 0-39 0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m1332 9c-8.09-2.28-18.86-0.63-29-1s-21.68 0.22-32 0-21.73 0.21-32 0c-10.26-0.21-22.03 0.36-31.97-0.02-9.95-0.38-4.03 14.81-5.03 23.02s-1.01 20.99 2 27c10.14-2.29 21.41-0.36 32-1 0.01 58.19-0.01 117.5 0 175 19.39-0.05 41.62 0 61 0 2.32-57.11 0.34-116.87 1-175 11.25-0.64 23.17 1.3 34-1-0.03-14.69-0.03-32.29 0-47z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m1391 236h32c7.83-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45 2.58-5.82 5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62 0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.06-26.37 0-39c-0.05-12.63 0.2-26.42 0-39s0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m1601 116c14.38-3.23 19.95-14.48 21.79-27.77 1.83-13.29 0.81-35.75-2.08-46.93-2.89-11.19-11.22-21.12-22.41-26.59-11.18-5.46-25.16-6.79-43.05-7.51-17.9-0.73-44.81 0.16-63.25-0.2-3.95 22.39-1.59 49.19-2 74s0.02 52.14 0 77-0.8 50.24 1 74c19.67-0.72 42.64 1.34 62-1-0.03-31.81 0.02-65.47 0-98 3.65 0.73 6.39 2.55 9 2 4.51 12.89 2.48 30.97 3 47s-1.3 35.79 1 50c17.68-0.02 38.3-0.02 56 0 3.92-22.03 1.74-56.89 1.78-78.78s-7.14-29.17-22.78-37.22m-48-22v-43c12.75-0.75 11.12 10.22 11 21s2.56 21.91-11 22z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".05" stroke="None"><path d="m568 191c13.01 7.08 11.95-9.93 12-23s0.36-33.3 0-47 1-33.97 0-47 3.26-27.82-10-28c-4.58 19.85-1.42 46.94-2 71s-0.15 51.79 0 74z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".05" stroke="None"><path d="m1701 191c13.01 7.08 11.95-9.93 12-23s0.36-33.3 0-47 1-33.97 0-47 3.26-27.82-10-28c-4.58 19.86-1.42 46.94-2 71s-0.15 51.79 0 74z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".04" stroke="None"><path d="m71 94c13.56-0.09 10.88-11.22 11-22s1.75-21.75-11-21v43z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".04" stroke="None"><path d="m1553 94c13.56-0.09 10.88-11.22 11-22s1.75-21.75-11-21v43z"/></g></svg>');
  /* SVG data for a black square */
  background-size: auto 100%;
  /* Ensure the background image covers the height of the container */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  /* Start the square from the left edge */
  animation: drawSquare 4s forwards;
  /* Apply the animation */
}

@keyframes drawSquare {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    /* Start with no width */
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    /* End with full width */
  }
}
<div class="kul">
  <!-- svg goes here, no characters to paste it -->
  <div class="kosa"></div>
</div>




It would be better to link the animation's behavior to an onload event rather than just display it for a fixed amount of time. There is a similar question and a solution in this post.

There are many possible ways, the idea is by default to show the pre-loader and when body completed loading (onload) you can change what is shown.
Just remember page is rendered from top to bottom so place the hiding rules first, before the body gets chance to load. Also all the animation rules should come before the rest of page.
For hiding and showing I went a little creative with opacity property.
Note: position of pre-loader is absolute and pointer-events: none so it wont interfere with the page.


function done_loading() {

  // added timeout for demonstration purpose
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.classList.remove("loading")
  }, 500)

}
main {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.kosa {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.kul {
  position: relative;
  /* display: none; */
}

.svg1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -140;
}

.kul svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.kosa::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<%3Fxml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"%3F><svg viewBox="0 0 1795 236" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:v="https://svgstorm.com"><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".02" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m0 236h209c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39c0.06 12.63 0.06 26.57 0 39s0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.78 11.8-5.37 17.62s-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45c-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.93 4.06-17.75 5.81h316c-19.13-5.24-37.25-12.86-45.39-33.75-8.15-20.9-9.08-62.22-7.61-91.25s-1.8-59.99 9.13-77.92 27.97-29.15 49.87-29.08c-0.42-3.28-5.45-0.46-5-4h-558v236m119-120c15.64 8.05 22.82 15.33 22.78 37.22s2.13 56.75-1.78 78.78c-17.7-0.02-38.32-0.02-56 0-2.3-14.21-0.48-33.97-1-50s1.51-34.11-3-47c-2.61 0.55-5.35-1.27-9-2 0.02 32.53-0.03 66.19 0 98-19.63 1.67-43.47 1.64-63 0v-222c20.39-5.47 56.89-0.34 77.22-0.22 20.34 0.12 35.02 3.46 45.86 17.14 10.85 13.67 9.95 29.34 10.92 50.08s-5.71 33.73-23 40m267-109c4.92 12.85 5.33 26.69 7.66 40.68s3.39 25.96 5.34 40.32c5.7-27.99 5.78-54.54 12-81 25.07 1.33 55.51-2.64 79 2-0.67 73.41 1.34 149.34-1 223-17.05-0.06-36.97 0.01-54 0-3-32.67 1-67.74-2-100-4.49 34.03-7.52 68.31-14 100-12.05-0.04-26.96-0.04-39 0-7.05-35.2-8.76-65.57-16-101-0.66 33.58 1.33 67.87-1 101-17.33-0.67-38.06 1.29-55-1v-222c10.81-2.5 25.19-0.26 38-1s27.52 1.38 40-1z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m557 236h31c19.26-4.31 38.94-11.66 47.8-33.25s7.48-58.31 7.2-88.75 1.76-62.52-9.13-80.92c-10.89-18.39-29.19-29.08-51.87-30.08 0.3-1.25 1.83-1.71 2-3h-26c-0.45 3.54 4.58 0.72 5 4-21.9-0.07-38.94 11.15-49.87 29.08s-7.66 48.89-9.13 77.92-0.54 70.35 7.61 91.25c8.14 20.89 26.26 28.51 45.39 33.75m11-45c-0.15-22.21-0.58-49.94 0-74s-2.58-51.15 2-71c13.26 0.18 9 14.97 10 28s-0.36 33.3 0 47 0.05 33.93 0 47 1.01 30.08-12 23z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".02" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m588 236h524c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39 0.06 26.57 0 39 0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.78 11.8-5.37 17.62s-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45c-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.92 4.06-17.75 5.81h247c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39c0.06 12.63 0.06 26.57 0 39s0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.79 11.8-5.37 17.62-2.59 5.82-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.92 4.06-17.75 5.81h267c-19.61-6.41-38.84-12.46-46.19-35.25s-8.67-68.84-6.81-98.75-2.12-57.24 12.3-74.7c14.41-17.47 33.06-25.48 58.7-25.3s44.21 9.96 57.13 27.92 10.17 48.33 10.87 79.08 1.36 69.42-6.58 91.77c-7.93 22.35-28.07 30.54-47.42 35.23h73v-236h-1211c-0.17 1.29-1.7 1.75-2 3 22.68 1 40.98 11.69 51.87 30.08 10.89 18.4 8.85 50.48 9.13 80.92s1.66 67.16-7.2 88.75-28.54 28.94-47.8 33.25m319-231c2.19 16.35 0.63 35.55 1 54s-0.27 38.27 0 57-0.35 38.16 0 57-1.09 38.59 1 57c-13.03 3.16-31.53-1.1-46 2-2.18-13.41-0.67-29.47-1-45s0.17-32.13 0-48 0.13-33.02 0-49c-41.48 47.69-83.78 94.09-125 142-16.76-1.62-35.27-1.69-52 0-1.88-1.73-1.1-3.04-2-5 51.5-57.3 103.25-115.92 155-175-51.24 0.67-103.2-1.33-154 1-3.16-13.02 1.1-31.53-2-46 16.35-2.19 35.54-0.63 54-1s38.27 0.27 57 0 38.16 0.34 57 0 38.59 1.09 57-1m146 50c-10.49 4.76-26.95 0.62-40 2v36h35c1.63 15.14 1.63 31.85 0 47h-35c0.02 30.19-0.03 61.53 0 91-19.36 2.34-42.33 0.28-62 1-2.34-72.99-0.32-149.73-1-223 9.97-1.85 24.1-1.16 36-1s27.36-0.78 39 0 28.1-5.48 27 8 0 26.1 1 39m279-46c-0.03 14.71-0.03 32.31 0 47-10.83 2.3-22.75 0.36-34 1-0.66 58.13 1.32 117.89-1 175-19.38 0-41.61-0.05-61 0-0.01-57.5 0.01-116.81 0-175-10.59 0.64-21.86-1.29-32 1-3.01-6.01-3-18.79-2-27s-4.92-23.4 5.03-23.02c9.94 0.38 21.71-0.19 31.97 0.02 10.27 0.21 21.68-0.22 32 0s21.86-0.37 32 0 20.91-1.28 29 1m269 107c15.64 8.05 22.82 15.33 22.78 37.22s2.14 56.75-1.78 78.78c-17.7-0.02-38.32-0.02-56 0-2.3-14.21-0.48-33.97-1-50s1.51-34.11-3-47c-2.61 0.55-5.35-1.27-9-2 0.02 32.53-0.03 66.19 0 98-19.36 2.34-42.33 0.28-62 1-1.8-23.76-1.02-49.14-1-74s-0.41-52.19 0-77-1.95-51.61 2-74c18.44 0.36 45.35-0.53 63.25 0.2 17.89 0.72 31.87 2.05 43.05 7.51 11.19 5.47 19.52 15.4 22.41 26.59 2.89 11.18 3.91 33.64 2.08 46.93-1.84 13.29-7.41 24.54-21.79 27.77z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1690 236h32c19.35-4.69 39.49-12.88 47.42-35.23 7.94-22.35 7.28-61.02 6.58-91.77s2.05-61.12-10.87-79.08-31.49-27.74-57.13-27.92-44.29 7.83-58.7 25.3c-14.42 17.46-10.44 44.79-12.3 74.7s-0.54 75.96 6.81 98.75 26.58 28.84 46.19 35.25m11-45c-0.15-22.21-0.58-49.94 0-74s-2.58-51.14 2-71c13.26 0.18 9 14.97 10 28s-0.36 33.3 0 47 0.05 33.93 0 47 1.01 30.08-12 23z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m907 5c-18.41 2.09-38.16 0.66-57 1s-38.27-0.27-57 0-38.54-0.37-57 0-37.65-1.19-54 1c3.1 14.47-1.16 32.98 2 46 50.8-2.33 102.76-0.33 154-1-51.75 59.08-103.5 117.7-155 175 0.9 1.96 0.12 3.27 2 5 16.73-1.69 35.24-1.62 52 0 41.22-47.91 83.52-94.31 125-142 0.13 15.98-0.17 33.13 0 49s-0.33 32.47 0 48-1.18 31.59 1 45c14.47-3.1 32.97 1.16 46-2-2.09-18.41-0.65-38.16-1-57s0.27-38.27 0-57 0.37-38.55 0-57 1.19-37.65-1-54z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m119 116c17.29-6.27 23.97-19.26 23-40s-0.07-36.41-10.92-50.08c-10.84-13.68-25.52-17.02-45.86-17.14-20.33-0.12-56.83-5.25-77.22 0.22v222c19.53 1.64 43.37 1.67 63 0-0.03-31.81 0.02-65.47 0-98 3.65 0.73 6.39 2.55 9 2 4.51 12.89 2.48 30.97 3 47s-1.3 35.79 1 50c17.68-0.02 38.3-0.02 56 0 3.91-22.03 1.74-56.89 1.78-78.78s-7.14-29.17-22.78-37.22m-48-22v-43c12.75-0.75 11.12 10.22 11 21s2.56 21.91-11 22z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m209 236h32c7.82-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45s5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62c0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.06-26.37 0-39c-0.05-12.63 0.2-26.42 0-39s0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m386 7c-12.48 2.38-27.19 0.26-40 1s-27.19-1.5-38 1v222c16.94 2.29 37.67 0.33 55 1 2.33-33.13 0.34-67.42 1-101 7.24 35.43 8.95 65.8 16 101 12.04-0.04 26.95-0.04 39 0 6.48-31.69 9.51-65.97 14-100 3 32.26-1 67.33 2 100 17.03 0.01 36.95-0.06 54 0 2.34-73.66 0.33-149.59 1-223-23.49-4.64-53.93-0.67-79-2-6.22 26.46-6.3 53.01-12 81-1.95-14.36-3.01-26.33-5.34-40.32s-2.74-27.83-7.66-40.68z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1053 55c-1-12.9-2.1-25.52-1-39s-15.36-7.22-27-8-27.1 0.16-39 0-26.03-0.85-36 1c0.68 73.27-1.34 150.01 1 223 19.67-0.72 42.64 1.34 62-1-0.03-29.47 0.02-60.81 0-91h35c1.63-15.15 1.63-31.86 0-47h-35v-36c13.05-1.38 29.51 2.76 40-2z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1112 236h32c7.83-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45s5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62c0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.05-26.37 0-39 0.2-26.42 0-39 0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1332 9c-8.09-2.28-18.86-0.63-29-1s-21.68 0.22-32 0-21.73 0.21-32 0c-10.26-0.21-22.03 0.36-31.97-0.02-9.95-0.38-4.03 14.81-5.03 23.02s-1.01 20.99 2 27c10.14-2.29 21.41-0.36 32-1 0.01 58.19-0.01 117.5 0 175 19.39-0.05 41.62 0 61 0 2.32-57.11 0.34-116.87 1-175 11.25-0.64 23.17 1.3 34-1-0.03-14.69-0.03-32.29 0-47z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1391 236h32c7.83-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45 2.58-5.82 5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62 0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.06-26.37 0-39c-0.05-12.63 0.2-26.42 0-39s0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".99" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1601 116c14.38-3.23 19.95-14.48 21.79-27.77 1.83-13.29 0.81-35.75-2.08-46.93-2.89-11.19-11.22-21.12-22.41-26.59-11.18-5.46-25.16-6.79-43.05-7.51-17.9-0.73-44.81 0.16-63.25-0.2-3.95 22.39-1.59 49.19-2 74s0.02 52.14 0 77-0.8 50.24 1 74c19.67-0.72 42.64 1.34 62-1-0.03-31.81 0.02-65.47 0-98 3.65 0.73 6.39 2.55 9 2 4.51 12.89 2.48 30.97 3 47s-1.3 35.79 1 50c17.68-0.02 38.3-0.02 56 0 3.92-22.03 1.74-56.89 1.78-78.78s-7.14-29.17-22.78-37.22m-48-22v-43c12.75-0.75 11.12 10.22 11 21s2.56 21.91-11 22z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".05" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m568 191c13.01 7.08 11.95-9.93 12-23s0.36-33.3 0-47 1-33.97 0-47 3.26-27.82-10-28c-4.58 19.85-1.42 46.94-2 71s-0.15 51.79 0 74z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".05" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1701 191c13.01 7.08 11.95-9.93 12-23s0.36-33.3 0-47 1-33.97 0-47 3.26-27.82-10-28c-4.58 19.86-1.42 46.94-2 71s-0.15 51.79 0 74z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".04" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m71 94c13.56-0.09 10.88-11.22 11-22s1.75-21.75-11-21v43z"/></g><g fill="None" fill-opacity="0" stroke="%23000" stroke-opacity=".04" stroke-width=".3"><path d="m1553 94c13.56-0.09 10.88-11.22 11-22s1.75-21.75-11-21v43z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".02" stroke="None"><path d="m0 236h209c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39c0.06 12.63 0.06 26.57 0 39s0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.78 11.8-5.37 17.62s-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45c-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.93 4.06-17.75 5.81h316c-19.13-5.24-37.25-12.86-45.39-33.75-8.15-20.9-9.08-62.22-7.61-91.25s-1.8-59.99 9.13-77.92 27.97-29.15 49.87-29.08c-0.42-3.28-5.45-0.46-5-4h-558v236m119-120c15.64 8.05 22.82 15.33 22.78 37.22s2.13 56.75-1.78 78.78c-17.7-0.02-38.32-0.02-56 0-2.3-14.21-0.48-33.97-1-50s1.51-34.11-3-47c-2.61 0.55-5.35-1.27-9-2 0.02 32.53-0.03 66.19 0 98-19.63 1.67-43.47 1.64-63 0v-222c20.39-5.47 56.89-0.34 77.22-0.22 20.34 0.12 35.02 3.46 45.86 17.14 10.85 13.67 9.95 29.34 10.92 50.08s-5.71 33.73-23 40m267-109c4.92 12.85 5.33 26.69 7.66 40.68s3.39 25.96 5.34 40.32c5.7-27.99 5.78-54.54 12-81 25.07 1.33 55.51-2.64 79 2-0.67 73.41 1.34 149.34-1 223-17.05-0.06-36.97 0.01-54 0-3-32.67 1-67.74-2-100-4.49 34.03-7.52 68.31-14 100-12.05-0.04-26.96-0.04-39 0-7.05-35.2-8.76-65.57-16-101-0.66 33.58 1.33 67.87-1 101-17.33-0.67-38.06 1.29-55-1v-222c10.81-2.5 25.19-0.26 38-1s27.52 1.38 40-1z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m557 236h31c19.26-4.31 38.94-11.66 47.8-33.25s7.48-58.31 7.2-88.75 1.76-62.52-9.13-80.92c-10.89-18.39-29.19-29.08-51.87-30.08 0.3-1.25 1.83-1.71 2-3h-26c-0.45 3.54 4.58 0.72 5 4-21.9-0.07-38.94 11.15-49.87 29.08s-7.66 48.89-9.13 77.92-0.54 70.35 7.61 91.25c8.14 20.89 26.26 28.51 45.39 33.75m11-45c-0.15-22.21-0.58-49.94 0-74s-2.58-51.15 2-71c13.26 0.18 9 14.97 10 28s-0.36 33.3 0 47 0.05 33.93 0 47 1.01 30.08-12 23z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".02" stroke="None"><path d="m588 236h524c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39 0.06 26.57 0 39 0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.78 11.8-5.37 17.62s-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45c-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.92 4.06-17.75 5.81h247c-9.63-2.59-17.37-5.67-23.92-9.13-6.54-3.46-16.01-9.47-19.47-17.62-3.47-8.16-8.01-11-8.54-23.33-0.54-12.33-0.05-30.12-0.07-44.92s-0.32-33.66 0-49-0.84-34.89 0-50-6.67-35.87 11-34 32.13-0.57 49-1c4.1 9.42 1.51 21.75 2 34s-0.2 26.42 0 39-0.05 26.37 0 39c0.06 12.63 0.06 26.57 0 39s0.93 23.11 1 34c2.76 2.89 5.3 0.8 8 1 1.81-9.99 1.45-18.79 2-31s-0.34-27.35 0-40-0.35-26.25 0-39-0.59-27.42 0-40-2.18-26.19 2-36c9.57 3.13 24.44-0.76 34 1s26.29-5.74 27 6c0.7 11.75-0.35 24.28 0 36s-0.21 23.38 0 35-0.22 24.61 0 36-0.39 24.19 0 35-0.98 21.99-1.34 30.68c-0.35 8.69-2.79 11.8-5.37 17.62-2.59 5.82-5.6 10.31-11.54 16.45-5.94 6.15-9.99 6.61-16 9.44-6 2.84-9.92 4.06-17.75 5.81h267c-19.61-6.41-38.84-12.46-46.19-35.25s-8.67-68.84-6.81-98.75-2.12-57.24 12.3-74.7c14.41-17.47 33.06-25.48 58.7-25.3s44.21 9.96 57.13 27.92 10.17 48.33 10.87 79.08 1.36 69.42-6.58 91.77c-7.93 22.35-28.07 30.54-47.42 35.23h73v-236h-1211c-0.17 1.29-1.7 1.75-2 3 22.68 1 40.98 11.69 51.87 30.08 10.89 18.4 8.85 50.48 9.13 80.92s1.66 67.16-7.2 88.75-28.54 28.94-47.8 33.25m319-231c2.19 16.35 0.63 35.55 1 54s-0.27 38.27 0 57-0.35 38.16 0 57-1.09 38.59 1 57c-13.03 3.16-31.53-1.1-46 2-2.18-13.41-0.67-29.47-1-45s0.17-32.13 0-48 0.13-33.02 0-49c-41.48 47.69-83.78 94.09-125 142-16.76-1.62-35.27-1.69-52 0-1.88-1.73-1.1-3.04-2-5 51.5-57.3 103.25-115.92 155-175-51.24 0.67-103.2-1.33-154 1-3.16-13.02 1.1-31.53-2-46 16.35-2.19 35.54-0.63 54-1s38.27 0.27 57 0 38.16 0.34 57 0 38.59 1.09 57-1m146 50c-10.49 4.76-26.95 0.62-40 2v36h35c1.63 15.14 1.63 31.85 0 47h-35c0.02 30.19-0.03 61.53 0 91-19.36 2.34-42.33 0.28-62 1-2.34-72.99-0.32-149.73-1-223 9.97-1.85 24.1-1.16 36-1s27.36-0.78 39 0 28.1-5.48 27 8 0 26.1 1 39m279-46c-0.03 14.71-0.03 32.31 0 47-10.83 2.3-22.75 0.36-34 1-0.66 58.13 1.32 117.89-1 175-19.38 0-41.61-0.05-61 0-0.01-57.5 0.01-116.81 0-175-10.59 0.64-21.86-1.29-32 1-3.01-6.01-3-18.79-2-27s-4.92-23.4 5.03-23.02c9.94 0.38 21.71-0.19 31.97 0.02 10.27 0.21 21.68-0.22 32 0s21.86-0.37 32 0 20.91-1.28 29 1m269 107c15.64 8.05 22.82 15.33 22.78 37.22s2.14 56.75-1.78 78.78c-17.7-0.02-38.32-0.02-56 0-2.3-14.21-0.48-33.97-1-50s1.51-34.11-3-47c-2.61 0.55-5.35-1.27-9-2 0.02 32.53-0.03 66.19 0 98-19.36 2.34-42.33 0.28-62 1-1.8-23.76-1.02-49.14-1-74s-0.41-52.19 0-77-1.95-51.61 2-74c18.44 0.36 45.35-0.53 63.25 0.2 17.89 0.72 31.87 2.05 43.05 7.51 11.19 5.47 19.52 15.4 22.41 26.59 2.89 11.18 3.91 33.64 2.08 46.93-1.84 13.29-7.41 24.54-21.79 27.77z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m1690 236h32c19.35-4.69 39.49-12.88 47.42-35.23 7.94-22.35 7.28-61.02 6.58-91.77s2.05-61.12-10.87-79.08-31.49-27.74-57.13-27.92-44.29 7.83-58.7 25.3c-14.42 17.46-10.44 44.79-12.3 74.7s-0.54 75.96 6.81 98.75 26.58 28.84 46.19 35.25m11-45c-0.15-22.21-0.58-49.94 0-74s-2.58-51.14 2-71c13.26 0.18 9 14.97 10 28s-0.36 33.3 0 47 0.05 33.93 0 47 1.01 30.08-12 23z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m907 5c-18.41 2.09-38.16 0.66-57 1s-38.27-0.27-57 0-38.54-0.37-57 0-37.65-1.19-54 1c3.1 14.47-1.16 32.98 2 46 50.8-2.33 102.76-0.33 154-1-51.75 59.08-103.5 117.7-155 175 0.9 1.96 0.12 3.27 2 5 16.73-1.69 35.24-1.62 52 0 41.22-47.91 83.52-94.31 125-142 0.13 15.98-0.17 33.13 0 49s-0.33 32.47 0 48-1.18 31.59 1 45c14.47-3.1 32.97 1.16 46-2-2.09-18.41-0.65-38.16-1-57s0.27-38.27 0-57 0.37-38.55 0-57 1.19-37.65-1-54z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m119 116c17.29-6.27 23.97-19.26 23-40s-0.07-36.41-10.92-50.08c-10.84-13.68-25.52-17.02-45.86-17.14-20.33-0.12-56.83-5.25-77.22 0.22v222c19.53 1.64 43.37 1.67 63 0-0.03-31.81 0.02-65.47 0-98 3.65 0.73 6.39 2.55 9 2 4.51 12.89 2.48 30.97 3 47s-1.3 35.79 1 50c17.68-0.02 38.3-0.02 56 0 3.91-22.03 1.74-56.89 1.78-78.78s-7.14-29.17-22.78-37.22m-48-22v-43c12.75-0.75 11.12 10.22 11 21s2.56 21.91-11 22z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m209 236h32c7.82-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45s5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62c0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.06-26.37 0-39c-0.05-12.63 0.2-26.42 0-39s0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m386 7c-12.48 2.38-27.19 0.26-40 1s-27.19-1.5-38 1v222c16.94 2.29 37.67 0.33 55 1 2.33-33.13 0.34-67.42 1-101 7.24 35.43 8.95 65.8 16 101 12.04-0.04 26.95-0.04 39 0 6.48-31.69 9.51-65.97 14-100 3 32.26-1 67.33 2 100 17.03 0.01 36.95-0.06 54 0 2.34-73.66 0.33-149.59 1-223-23.49-4.64-53.93-0.67-79-2-6.22 26.46-6.3 53.01-12 81-1.95-14.36-3.01-26.33-5.34-40.32s-2.74-27.83-7.66-40.68z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m1053 55c-1-12.9-2.1-25.52-1-39s-15.36-7.22-27-8-27.1 0.16-39 0-26.03-0.85-36 1c0.68 73.27-1.34 150.01 1 223 19.67-0.72 42.64 1.34 62-1-0.03-29.47 0.02-60.81 0-91h35c1.63-15.15 1.63-31.86 0-47h-35v-36c13.05-1.38 29.51 2.76 40-2z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m1112 236h32c7.83-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45s5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62c0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.05-26.37 0-39 0.2-26.42 0-39 0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m1332 9c-8.09-2.28-18.86-0.63-29-1s-21.68 0.22-32 0-21.73 0.21-32 0c-10.26-0.21-22.03 0.36-31.97-0.02-9.95-0.38-4.03 14.81-5.03 23.02s-1.01 20.99 2 27c10.14-2.29 21.41-0.36 32-1 0.01 58.19-0.01 117.5 0 175 19.39-0.05 41.62 0 61 0 2.32-57.11 0.34-116.87 1-175 11.25-0.64 23.17 1.3 34-1-0.03-14.69-0.03-32.29 0-47z"/></g><g stroke="None"><path d="m1391 236h32c7.83-1.75 11.75-2.97 17.75-5.81 6.01-2.83 10.06-3.29 16-9.44 5.94-6.14 8.95-10.63 11.54-16.45 2.58-5.82 5.02-8.93 5.37-17.62 0.36-8.69 1.73-19.87 1.34-30.68s0.22-23.61 0-35 0.21-24.38 0-36 0.35-23.28 0-35 0.7-24.25 0-36c-0.71-11.74-17.44-4.24-27-6s-24.43 2.13-34-1c-4.18 9.81-1.41 23.42-2 36s0.35 27.25 0 40 0.34 26.35 0 39 0.55 27.79 0 40-0.19 21.01-2 31c-2.7-0.2-5.24 1.89-8-1-0.07-10.89-1.06-21.57-1-34s0.06-26.37 0-39c-0.05-12.63 0.2-26.42 0-39s0.49-26.75 0-39 2.1-24.58-2-34c-16.87 0.43-31.33 2.87-49 1s-10.16 18.89-11 34 0.32 34.66 0 50-0.02 34.2 0 49-0.47 32.59 0.07 44.92c0.53 12.33 5.07 15.17 8.54 23.33 3.46 8.15 12.93 14.16 19.47 17.62 6.55 3.46 14.29 6.54 23.92 9.13z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".99" stroke="None"><path d="m1601 116c14.38-3.23 19.95-14.48 21.79-27.77 1.83-13.29 0.81-35.75-2.08-46.93-2.89-11.19-11.22-21.12-22.41-26.59-11.18-5.46-25.16-6.79-43.05-7.51-17.9-0.73-44.81 0.16-63.25-0.2-3.95 22.39-1.59 49.19-2 74s0.02 52.14 0 77-0.8 50.24 1 74c19.67-0.72 42.64 1.34 62-1-0.03-31.81 0.02-65.47 0-98 3.65 0.73 6.39 2.55 9 2 4.51 12.89 2.48 30.97 3 47s-1.3 35.79 1 50c17.68-0.02 38.3-0.02 56 0 3.92-22.03 1.74-56.89 1.78-78.78s-7.14-29.17-22.78-37.22m-48-22v-43c12.75-0.75 11.12 10.22 11 21s2.56 21.91-11 22z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".05" stroke="None"><path d="m568 191c13.01 7.08 11.95-9.93 12-23s0.36-33.3 0-47 1-33.97 0-47 3.26-27.82-10-28c-4.58 19.85-1.42 46.94-2 71s-0.15 51.79 0 74z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".05" stroke="None"><path d="m1701 191c13.01 7.08 11.95-9.93 12-23s0.36-33.3 0-47 1-33.97 0-47 3.26-27.82-10-28c-4.58 19.86-1.42 46.94-2 71s-0.15 51.79 0 74z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".04" stroke="None"><path d="m71 94c13.56-0.09 10.88-11.22 11-22s1.75-21.75-11-21v43z"/></g><g fill-opacity=".04" stroke="None"><path d="m1553 94c13.56-0.09 10.88-11.22 11-22s1.75-21.75-11-21v43z"/></g></svg>');
  /* SVG data for a black square */
  background-size: auto 100%;
  /* Ensure the background image covers the height of the container */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  /* Start the square from the left edge */
  animation: drawSquare 4s forwards;
  /* Apply the animation */
}

@keyframes drawSquare {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    /* Start with no width */
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    /* End with full width */
  }
}
<style>
  .loading main {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .loading .preloader {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  main {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 250ms;
  }
  
  .preloader {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 250ms;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>

<body onload="done_loading()" class="loading">
  <div class="preloader">
    <div class="kul">
      <!-- svg goes here, no characters to paste it -->
      <div class="kosa"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <main>
    <h1>This is content of website...</h1>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
  </main>

</body>



